# Auth0 and Asp.Net Core 2.0 Razor Pages LoginPath Issue

Tags: razor, auth0, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm creating a Razor Pages app with Auth0 as the authentication provider and I'm running into a LoginPath issue. I've seen other StackOverflow answers that say you should put this into the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Index/Login");
```

I tried putting that below the **services.AddAuthentication** section of code, but that doesn't redirect to /Index/Login. I'm not seeing anywhere else how to properly get an [Authorize] attribute failure to redirect to the Auth0 login page. I figured if I could get the path set to the Index page this code would run:

```
public async void OnGetLogin(string returnUrl = "/")
{
  await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
}
```

My full ConfigureServices code is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add authentication services
    services.AddAuthentication(options => {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;                 
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
        // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
        options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

        // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
        options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

        // Set response type to code
        options.ResponseType = "code";

        // Configure the scope
        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("groups");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");                                

        // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:5000/signin-auth0 
        // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard 
        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-auth0");

        // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
        options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            // handle the logout redirection 
            OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
            {
                var logoutUri = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

                var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                {
                    if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                    {
                // transform to absolute
                var request = context.Request;
                        postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                    }
                    logoutUri += $"&returnTo={ Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                }

                context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                context.HandleResponse();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Index/Login");

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Anyone know how to do this properly in 2.0?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? i am trying to also use razor pages together with Auth0 and cant figure this out.

Comment: @hs2d I didn't. no. I ended up using Azure B2C and it works a lot better with the .NET Core web apps.

Comment: @Rob,do u have any working github sample with Razor Pages  and B2C ?

Comment: @Venky I don't - I ended up going with Azure B2C. So at this point I can't verify that Raphael's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this snippet in order to work:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/");
        options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Login");
    });
```

When I added this, my code started to work and redirect to the right login page.